# Android: Workaround for support.v4.app.Fragment -> Fragment classcastexception?

Tags: android, android-fragments, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to add a `support.v4.app.Fragment` to a `PreferenceActivity` header, like so:

```
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.SupportFragmentSubClass"
    android:title="Selecting this should show the accompanying fragment" >
</header>
```

This throws a ClassCastException, presumably because the PreferenceActivity is expecting a sub-class of `android.app.Fragment`, rather than `support.v4.app.Fragment`.

My use case is this:
I have non-standard Fragment that I want to use as a preference on both <3.0 and >3.0 devices. For >=3.0, I need an `android.app.Fragment` subclass so it can be embedded in the 'detail pane' of the preferences activity on tablet devices. For <3.0, I need a `v4.support.app.Fragment` subclass so I can throw in it an `ActivityFragment`.

Is there a workaround that would allow me to use a compatibility Fragment in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PreferenceFragment` is not in the Android Support package, and you cannot use an Android Support package Fragment class in a `PreferenceActivity` this way. Moreover, your headers would not work on Android 2.x anyway, since the `PreferenceActivity` in Android 2.x does not know about fragments.

In principle, you could fork the `PreferenceActivity` from the source code to create one that does use the Android Support version of `Fragment`.

Or, organize your preferences to use fragments on Android 3.0+ and avoid them on Android 2.x. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) where I demonstrate a way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think @CommonsWare 's solution is perfect. Actually, we need a PreferenceFragment compat. Because PreferenceFragment can be placed in any layout of any activity even the activity extends from ActionBarActivity. PreferenceActivity doesn't extends from ActionBarActivity, it does not have consistent ActionBar layout in all android versions.

Answer (score 2):

As @CommonsWare points out, it's not possible to what I wanted without rewriting PreferenceActivity, and that looks like a load of work.

The not-so-elegant solution I settled on was to create two PreferenceActivities ([as shown here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC)) and also create two Fragment subclasses, one for each flavour of Fragment.

So, `PrefsActivityHC` adds this header:

```
<header
    <!-- An android.app.Fragment subclass -->
    android:fragment="com.example.project.MyFragmentHC"
</header>
```

...while `PrefsActivity` adds this preference:

```
<Preference>
    <intent
        <!-- A v4.support.app.Fragment subclass, wrapped in an ActivityFragment -->
        android:targetClass="com.example.project.MyFragmentActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.project" >
    </intent>
</Preference>
```

To minimise the amount of code duplication required to have two near-identical fragments, I created a `MyFragmentDelegate` class that supports common fragment methods, and held an instance of that in `MyFragment` and `MyFragmentHC`. Calls to the methods in these fragments are then just forwarded to the delegate:

```
class MyFragment {

    MyFragmentDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return mDelegate.onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    }
}

class MyFragmentHC {

    MyFragmentDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return mDelegate.onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    }
}
```